# Why isn't my Push Notification appearing on the device when the log shows that there is no error?

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, android-notifications

I have deployed the following firebase function for implementing push notifications in my cloud firestore chat app. I am doing this for the first time after watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6jMKQ9zo-o&lc=z22lzdth5reseha5h04t1aokgck50fd20sfpuvltsywkbk0h00410.1581234112955648&feature=em-comments).

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationToTopic = functions.firestore.document('chats/{roomid}/messages/{uid}').onWrite(async(event)=>{
    let content = event.after.get('message')
    var message ={
        notification: {
            title: 'You have an unread message',
            body: content,
        },
        topic:'namelesscoder',
    };
});
```

While testing the function, the [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT8Fk.jpg) shows the function to be properly working without any errors, however my device isn't actually getting the notification. Is this because of the way I have declared the database structure? The path in code mentioned above is where is store my chat messages.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will send push notifications to a topic (group of users who are subscribed to a topic) rather than a specific user. In case you want to send notification to a group of users, you can use this function and your users must be subscribed to topic. In this function, topic is 'namelesscoder', so your user needs to be subscribed to this topic.

If you are on android, write following code to subscribe to topic 'namelesscoder'

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("namelesscoder")
   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
             String msg = "subscribed to topic nameless coder.";
             if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                 msg = "Failed to subscribe to topic";
             }
          Log.d(TAG, msg);
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
});
```

In case you wanna send notification to a specific user, you must send it to a FCM token.